# Globally Style UINavBar and UITabBar seperator color and width

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to style a `UINavigationBar`'s bottom separator and a `UITabBar`'s top separator globally? If not, how would one do that on a per instance basis?

---

**What I've tried**

For a `UITabBar`

```
UITabBar.appearance().borderColor = UIColor.green
UITabBar.appearance().borderWidth = 4
```

Similarly for a `UINavigationBar`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().borderColor = UIColor.green
UINavigationBar.appearance().borderWidth = 4
```

This has the effect of surrounding the respective bar with a green border of `4pt`s, but the separator between `UINavBar` and `UITabBar` and the content still appears to be a black line of `1pt` width.